# Evaluate $\lim_{x \rightarrow \pi/2}\left(\arctan(x/(\tan(x)-x))/(x-\pi/2)\right)?$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, limits-without-lhopital

I need to evaluate this limit without L'Hospital's Rule but I haven't found a method. $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \pi/2}\left(\arctan(x/(\tan(x)-x))/(x-\pi/2)\right)$$

Comment: Try computing the limit by writing the problem in the form
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \frac{\pi }{2}} \frac{{\arctan \left( {\frac{x}{{\tan x - x}}} \right)}}{{\frac{x}{{\tan x - x}}}} \times \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \frac{\pi }{2}} \frac{x}{{\tan x - x}}\frac{1}{{x - \frac{\pi }{2}}}.
$$

Comment: @Gary still nothing i keep getting 1×0×inf

Comment: Hint: $$
\tan x =  - \frac{1}{{\tan \left( {x - \frac{\pi }{2}} \right)}} =  - \frac{{x - \frac{\pi }{2}}}{{\tan \left( {x - \frac{\pi }{2}} \right)}}\frac{1}{{x - \frac{\pi }{2}}}.
$$ Also, do not separate the last fraction when calculating the limit after the $\arctan$ bit.

Comment: @Gary Thats very helpful thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\lim_{x\to \pi/2}{\arctan\left(\frac{x}{\tan(x)-x}\right)}=0$. Then this is just the limit definition of the derivative:

$$
\lim_{x\to \pi/2}\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{x}{\tan(x)-x}\right)-0}{x-\pi/2}
$$
$$
= \lim_{x\to \pi/2}\frac{d}{dx}{\arctan\left(\frac{x}{\tan(x)-x}\right)}
$$A tedious chain-rule calculation produces:
$$
= \lim_{x\to \pi/2}\frac{- x \sec^2(x)+\tan(x) }{\tan^2(x)+2 x^2  - 2 x \tan(x)}
$$
Multiply through by $\cos^2(x)$ to evaluate the limit.
$$
= \lim_{x\to \pi/2}\frac{-x+\sin(x)\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x) +2 x^2\cos^2(x) - 2 x \sin(x)\cos(x)} = \frac{-\pi/2+0}{1+0+0}=\frac{-\pi}{2}
$$